# Save the value from database table in php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how to save a database table value in a php variable. So that when a user or web honour update the table value, the php variable value should not change.
e.g.

```
 $result=mysql_query("select * from users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row["username"]==$_SESSION['username'])
$save=$row["data"];
}
```

Let say if the table:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row["username"]==$_SESSION['username']) 
{
$data=$_POST["data"];
$query = "UPDATE users SET ,data='$data' WHERE username = '$_SESSION['username']'";
mysql_query($query);
}
}
```

The previous data will be lost and `$save` variable will contain new data that the user has updated. However, I want the `$save` variable to store the previous data using an array or something similar?

Comment: try keep in session will be better before update value $save[]=$row["data"];

Comment: If you want to retain a value, you have to *put* that value somewhere.  For what scope do you want to retain it?  The execution of the script?  The user's session?  Indefinitely?  Regardless of whether or not that value originally came from a database doesn't make it any different from *any* other value anywhere in your code.  If you want to keep a copy of it in code, assign it to a variable.  If you want it to follow the user's session, store it in the session.  If you want to persist it indefinitely, write it to a database.

Comment: i want to save it indefinitely.But i think i have to make variables in database for each update of data and before each update.e.g,if user updates the data 20 times.then 20 variables should be declared already.

Answer (score 0):

If you need history of values, you can save each change of value in a different table. In my example I just save id, table, field and new value. You can also save timestamp and log all changements of a single field.

```
create table updates (
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    table_name varchar(50) not null,
    field_name varchar(50) not null,
    field_value varchar(50) not null
);


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    if ($row["username"]==$_SESSION['username']) 
    {
      $col1 = $_POST["data"]['col1'];
      $col2 = $_POST["data"]['col2'];
      $col3 = $_POST["data"]['col3'];

      // save the log
      mysql_query('insert into updates values(NULL, "users", "col1", "' . $col1 . '")');
      mysql_query('insert into updates values(NULL, "users", "col2", "' . $col2 . '")');
      mysql_query('insert into updates values(NULL, "users", "col3", "' . $col3 . '")');

      // change the value
      $query = "UPDATE users SET data='$data' WHERE username = '$_SESSION['username']'";
      mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Then, if you need history of 'users.col3' field, just run the query

```
select * from updates
where table_name = 'users'
and field_name = 'col3'
```

This returns all updates of this field.

PS. Remember to add in "updates" fields like user_id, timestamp and so on.

Comment: ok.i make another table.then e.g, user updates the data 15 times.then how to make 15 variables means i have to make variable in table or it can be done by user itself?

Comment: What do you mean with "how to make 15 variables means i have to make variable in table"?

Comment: let say user updates the data 15 times.So, i should have 15 columns for each update in the table.isn't it so?

Comment: Actually i am using xampp server.in table "updates",there will be each row for each user,and in each row,there should be enough columns,each updated data should be stored.So,it means for one update,there should be one column.i dont know i am true?.Actually,i'm not understanding how it will work without enough columns on xampp.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand if you need to store one value or you need to store entire history of a table. The problem to solve is save one record, one field, entire history of your database? Each problem, has a different solution.

Comment: i want to store entire history of three colums ( from the table )  of each user.

Comment: I am updateing my asnwer to explain  better hot to use updates